# Проблема с stdout_lines

Tags: ansible

Есть плейбук, который должен выводить версию ПО eltex в консоль при выполнении:

```
tasks:
    - name: dai versiu
      ios_command:
        commands: show version | include Version
      register: output

    - name: pechatai versiu
      debug:
        var: output.stdout_lines
```

По идее должен вывести следующее:

```
  Version: 4.0.16.5
  Version: 4.0.16.2
```

Но выводит это:

```
"output.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "2009         -                                                      S         ",
            "2010         -                                                      S         ",
            "2011         -                                                      S         ",
            "2012         -                                                      S         ",
            "2013         -                                                      S         ",
            "2014         -                                                      S         ",
            "2015         -                                                      S         ",
            "2016         -                                                      S         ",
            "2017         -                                                      S         ",
            "2018         -                                                      S         ",
            "2019         -                                                      S         ",
            "2020         -                                                      S         ",
            "2021         -                                                      S         ",
            "2022         -                                                      S         ",
            "2023         -                                                      S         ",
            "2024         -                                                      S         ",
            "2025         -                                                      S         ",
            "2026         -                                                      S         ",
            "2027         -                                                      S         ",
            "2028         -                                                      S         ",
            "2029         -                                                      S         ",
            "2030         -                                                      S         ",
            "                                                      ",
            "2031         -                                                      S         ",
            "2032         -                                                      S         ",
            "2033         -                                                      S         ",
            "2034         -                                                      S         ",
            "2035         -                                                      S         ",
            "2036         -                                                      S         ",
            "2037         -                                                      S         ",
            "2038         -                                                      S         ",
            "2039         -                                                      S         ",
            "2040         -                                                      S         ",
            "2041         -                                                      S         ",
            "2042         -                                                      S         ",
            "2043         -                                                      S         ",
            "2044         -                                                      S         ",
            "2045         -                                                      S         ",
            "2046         -                                                      S         ",
            "2047         -                                                      S         ",
            "2048         -                                                      S         ",
            "2049         -                                                      S         ",
            "2050         -                                                      S         ",
            "2051         -                                                      S         ",
            "2052         -                                                      S         ",
            "                                                      ",
            "2053         -                                                      S         ",
            "2054         -                                                      S         ",
            "2055         -                                                      S         ",
            "2056         -                                                      S         ",
            "2057         -                                                      S         ",
            "2058         -                                                      S         ",
            "2059         -                                                      S         ",
            "2060         -                                                      S         ",
            "2061         -                                                      S         ",
            "2062         -                                                      S         ",
            "2063         -                                                      S         ",
            "2064         -                                                      S         ",
            "2065         -                                                      S         ",
            "2066         -                                                      S         ",
            "2067         -                                                      S         ",
            "2068         -                                                      S         ",
            "2069         -                                                      S         ",
            "2070         -                                                      S         ",
            "2071         -                                                      S         ",
            "2072         -                                                      S         ",
            "2073         -                                                      S         ",
            "2074         -                                                      S         ",
            "                                                      ",
            "2075         -                                                      S         ",
            "2076         -                                                      S         ",
            "2077         -                                                      S         ",
            "2078         -                                                      S         ",
            "2079         -                                                      S         ",
            "2080         -                                                      S         ",
            "2081         -                                                      S         ",
            "2082         -                                                      S         ",
            "2083         -                                                      S         ",
            "2084         -                                                      S         ",
            "2085         -                                                      S         ",
            "2086         -                                                      S         ",
            "2087         -                                                      S         ",
            "2088         -                                                      S         ",
            "2089         -                                                      S         ",
            "2090         -                                                      S         ",
            "2091         -                                                      S         ",
            "2092         -                                                      S         ",
            "2093         -                                                      S         ",
            "2094         -                                                      S         ",
            "2095         -                                                      S         ",
            "2096         -                                                      S         ",
            "                                                      ",
            "2097         -                                                      S"
        ]
```

С `-vvv` примерно следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можно ли это дело превратить во что-то более понятное человеческому глазу? Или хотя бы как-то диагностировать, на какой стороне проблема?

Ansible 2.10.8

Comment: Ну а `show version | include Version` руками если запустить - чё выдаёт?

Comment: @donRumata Выдает то, что должно:   'Version: 4.0.16.5
  Version: 4.0.16.2'

Comment: А если плейбук с `-vvv` запустить?

Comment: @donRumata, в сам вопрос добавил вывод

Comment: А как шелл руками выводит нужное, а через ansible - какой-то мусор. У тебя там точно с переменными всё ок?

Comment: @donRumata, с переменными точно все норм. принимающей стороной является коммутатор eltex(российская пародия на циски), и, скорее всего, проблема где-то там, но как это точно выяснить, пока не понимаю(

Comment: А если добавить `environment` с `LC_ALL: C.UTF-8`?

Comment: @donRumata, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Так, а если это типа импортозамещение, самому вендору нельзя кинуть ссылку на вопрос? Пусть сюда придут и ответят.